# Why isn't this function tail recursive?

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I wrote a basic Eratosthenes's sieve function, that originally ended in `head::(innerSieve tail)`, which I noticed wasn't recursive.

Then I modified it as follows to use an accumulator. This code should be tail recursive now:

```
let Sieve n =     

    let rec innerSieve primes numbers =     
        match numbers with
        | [] -> primes
        | h :: t -> innerSieve (h :: primes) (List.filter (fun x -> x % h > 0) t) 

    innerSieve [] [2 .. n] |> List.rev

printf "%A" (Sieve 10000)
```

However, *even in release mode*, the memory usage of this function keeps growing extremely fast with the size of `n` (+1-2MB per every +1000). Am I missing something?

EDIT: Screenshot of VS running it with n = 100M:

[image]

Comment: TCO only means that the call stack won't pop.

Comment: Why do you think the memory usage is related to tail calls? Have you used a profiler?

Comment: Yes (see addition to question for screenshot). With n = 100M, the memory usage quickly surpasses 2GB and hits an OutOfMemoryException shortly thereafter. The snapshot feature can't terminate, but it detects millions of objects. With TCO, there should be at most a single list of numbers in memory, if I understand it correctly?

Comment: well 100.000.000 Int32 values will be  ~380MB alone (just from your [2..n]) - now add all the intermediate lists you are generating ... seems to add up ...

Comment: Carsten: but that's the point, isn't it? If it's doing TCO, then there **shouldn't ** be more than one intermediate list in memory at any given time, I think.

Comment: no - it just means that you don't allocate stuff for your function-calls on the stack

Comment: TCO is really *only* about the stack allocations related to the call itself. While it is in theory possible for a compiler to optimize other things, it doesn't mean that it is actually done. And F# doesn't do a whole lot of optimizations, really. You're not *copying* the whole lists, but you're still creating a lot of them. Immutable lists are "free" (not really) in theory, but rarely in practice :) Note that you got an `OutOfMemoryException`, not a `StackOverflowException` - it's the allocations you do on the *heap* that are killing you. Like... the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your question: the function **is** *tail recursive* - this does not mean that it's magically memory-effective though.

---

Your *real* problem is the way `List`s are handled/kept in memory (those get very big, very fast.

That's the problem with lists: they are not really optimal if they get big (to much overhead...) so the usual first step is to go arrays instead.

And yeah it works fine (memroy-wise) here:

```
let inline divides d n = n % d > 0

let rec innerSieve primes numbers =     
    if Array.isEmpty numbers
    then primes
    else 
        let h = numbers.[0]
        let numbers' = numbers |> Array.filter (divides h)
        in innerSieve (h :: primes) numbers'

let Sieve n =     
    innerSieve [] [| 2 .. n |] |> List.rev
```

of course this too will run *a long time* ... but on my machine the memory consumption is <200MB so not to bad IMO (...of course my machine is still thinking and will so for some while so probably I just kill the process again and call it a day - you can let it run instead ;) ).

---

BTW: it might be a fun excercise to switch this to `seq` instead of `list` so you can see the primes pop up one after another ... might make the wait time more pleasant

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty shocked at the magnitude difference between `List`and `Array`; I figured a linked list of integers was going to be, at worst, 2-3 times as big as the equivalent array, due to the cost of the pointer. Definitely something to keep in mind.